# MACRO for a runtime signature to printf

Tags: c, macros

Lets say I have a variable

```
const char *thread_name = "THREAD_1";
```

I want to know the definition of a macro called say, PRINT_SIG(sig) such that my printf outputs include [THREAD 1]. eg:

```
printf(PRINT_SIG(thread_name)" Hello I am a thread");
```

which should output:

```
[THREAD_1] Hello I am a thread
```

Edit: Obviously the value of 'thread_name' is not known at compile time because the 1 is appended based on how many threads are launched. the example is given just for simplicities sake.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with `printf` directly: you can put two string literals right next to each other and the compiler will join them, but not join a variable with a literal. Suspect that creating a variadic helper function to do this would be in order; first parameter would be the thread name, followed by the format and list of arguments.

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, they can't access variable values, since those don't exist until run-time.

Comment: Why not just make `thread_name` an argument to `printf()`, with `%s` in the format string?

Comment: Total nitpick: when assigning a string literal to a pointer, make sure the pointer is `const char *`, not `char *` unless you have an environment where strings are known to be writable.

Comment: @SteveFriedl - Thanks. good point. In actual code I am using char []. This is just for illustration - but Ill update this so others dont get the wrong idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after some tinkering around I used the following:

```
#define _GET_THREAD_NAME(tname) prctl(PR_GET_NAME,tname,0,0,0)
static inline void _timestamp(char* _pre_alloc_memory);

#define LVL_STRING(s) #s
#define LEVEL_WARN LVL_STRING(WARNING)
#define LEVEL_INFO LVL_STRING(INFO)
#define LEVEL_EROR LVL_STRING(ERROR)
#define LEVEL_DBUG LVL_STRING(DEBUG)
#define LOG_PREFIX "[%-s %-7s %11.11s ] "
#define PREFIX_ARGS(lvl) ts, LEVEL_##lvl, tname
#define NL "\n"
#define ERRNO ": %s"

#define logger_info(fmt, ... ) do{ \
_PREFIX_TS_TNAME; \
logger(LOG_PREFIX fmt NL, PREFIX_ARGS(INFO), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} while(0)

#define logger(fmt, ...) ffprint(file_handle, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define ffprint(file_handle, fmt, ...) do { \
fprintf(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);    \
fflush(stderr); \
} while(0)

#define _PREFIX_TS_TNAME char ts[100]; char tname[MAX_THREAD_NAME_SIZE]; _timestamp(ts); _GET_THREAD_NAME(tname)
```

This inline _timestamp function just uses `gmtime_r`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).